# Ssh host key verification

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have a Server behind a Port-forwarding Firewall.

```
Server <---> Firewall <------> NAT Port 222
                 |
                  -----------> VPN
```

I can ssh per key into it from the VPN.
Doing this on server:

```
sever:~> ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_rsa_host_key
```

Shows the HOSTKEY

I try to ssh into it from the outside:

```
ssh server.external
```

Results in "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED"

```
 The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
 HOSTKEY.EXTERN
```

The fingerprints HOSTKEY and HOSTKEY.EXTERN are different.

If I ssh into it via the VPN and its internal IP all is fine.

2 Questionts:

1. Why are HOSTKEY.EXTERN and HOSTKEY fingerprints different?
2. How can I check the reported host key from the outside?

***EDIT: Answer to Part 2 and more strange findings:***

I now did 'ssh-keyscan server' internally and externally,
two different keys are the result.

```
ssh-keyscan server.external > server.external.keyscan
ssh-keyscan server.internal > server.internal.keyscan
```

then I fingerprint those:

```
ssh-keygen -lf server.external.keyscan
ssh-keygen -lf server.internal.keyscan
```

Two different fingerprints.
I do not get it.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is picky in that the hostname *must* match for a given key in `known_hosts`. Because you're accessing it from the outside, your SSH client is seeing the server coming from external.ip instead of its internal address.

The best way I can think of to fix is to have two keypairs - one for external access, and one for internal. This way both will be in `known_hosts`.

Comment: I know why ssh is complaining, I do not know why these keys are different.

Comment: They aren't. It's complaining because SSH sees a different hostname than what it's *supposed* to be, which can signify a MITM attack even when it's not.

Comment: They are different. Or does the key fingerprint include the Hostname? Even the raw keys (the part after ssh-rsa) is different...

Comment: If the actual key is different that may be a sign you are seeing a MITM somewhere.  Are you using different clients from inside vs outside?  You might be getting the ecdsa key in one location and the rsa key in another?  You could have a new client in one of those locations?

Comment: BTW, you might consider setting two config in your ssh config file `~/.ssh/config`.  One for the external, and one for the internal.  Within both entries specify a `HostKeyAlias`.